# Logcat Filter for phonegap/cordova Plugin?

Tags: cordova, logging, terminal, logcat

When I use

```
Log.d("testTag","you can see this");
```

in my phonegap Plugin and try to filter Logcat in Terminal with

```
adb logcat -s testTag
```

nothing shows up. If I use logcat without filter, there are too many logs. Is there a clean way to show relevant logs in terminal with logcat?

Comment: `adb logcat testtag:D *:S` try this

Comment: doesn't work for me either. I was looking through the filterless logs and recognized, that the logs aren't shown up. So the problem must be between cordova and log.d().

Comment: nevermind, I changed the whole time the plugin outside of the android cordova files. Thank You for your help. Now it works :)

Comment: I am not sure about best way in terminal but on Mac LogRabbit has a very powerful filter options. Also make googling a log error just one click away and usually leads to StackOverflow ;)    (full disclosure I am the creator of LogRabbit).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure `android.util.Log` was imported or you can use explicitly

```
android.util.Log.d("testTag","you can see this");
```

Secondly, using filter with chromium, it means filter only app run by chromium engine(your cordova/phonegapp app)

```
adb logcat chromium
```

If some texts were printed out to console but not your expected text, definitely there're something wrong with your logic and your log can not be reachabe